# Getting QConsolidate to work in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins

Has anyone managed to get QConsolidate plugin to actually work with QGIS 3? It always gives me an `error on line 1` with no details as to the issue.

Comment: Try QPackage : http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QPackage/

Answer (score 3):

"Log Message Panel" gives more information about the error.

QGIS saves a project using a compressed format with the `.qgz` extension by default. The QGZ format is a compressed (zip) archive. QConsolidate doesn't work on QGZ files, but QGS file.

You get that error because the plugin expects the project file is a QGS file structured XML-like.

Try to save your project as QGS file. Open a new empty project. Then open your project that you have already saved. Then use QConsolidate plugin. It worked for me.